# Downloading Torrent with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss, bittorrent

I was wondering if anyone had an example of how to download a torrent using NodeJS? Essentially, I have an RSS Feed of torrents that I iterate through and grab the torrent file url, then would like to initiate a download of that torrent on the server.

I've parsed and looped through the RSS just fine, however I've tried a few npm packages but they've either crashed or were just unstable. If anyone has any suggestions, examples, anything... I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var options = {};
  parser.parseURL('rss feed here', options, function(err, articles) {
    var i = 0;
    var torrent;
    for (var title in articles.items) {
      console.log(articles.items[i]['url']);
      //download torrent here
      i++;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The bittorrent protocol is open and not complicated at all. If the existing packages suck, write one that doesn't :)

Comment: there are many different ways. you could interface with an external application, interface with node.js wrappers for a C library or use a native node.js torrent implementation.

Comment: @Touffy, that provided very little direction...

Comment: @the8472 Do you have any guides or articles on native node.js torrent implementation?

Comment: Why do you expect a guide? Either you implement your own (by reading the specification) or you look for existing libraries - which would be asking SO to recommend a library, which is offtopic.

Comment: @the8472 No where in my original post, nor comment did I demand or in any way expect a guide. I don't expect anything from you or this community. However, I have hopes that someone could of provided a little more direction than essentially "Go Google it". Did I receive the direction I was looking for? No. Does it matter to me? No. Do I have a problem with your rather obnoxious reply to my QUESTION? Absolutely. I have a desire to learn. But believe it or not, not everyone will learn the way you do.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [node-torrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-torrent) for this.

Then, to download a torrent:

```
var Client = require('node-torrent');
var client = new Client({logLevel: 'DEBUG'});
var torrent = client.addTorrent('a.torrent');

// when the torrent completes, move it's files to another area
torrent.on('complete', function() {
    console.log('complete!');
    torrent.files.forEach(function(file) {
        var newPath = '/new/path/' + file.path;
        fs.rename(file.path, newPath);
        // while still seeding need to make sure file.path points to the right place
        file.path = newPath;
    });
});
```

Alternatively, for more control, you can use [transmission-dæmon](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) and control it via its xml-rpc protocol. There's a node module called [transmission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transmission) that does the job! Exemple:

```
var Transmission = require('./')

var transmission = new Transmission({
    port : 9091,
    host : '127.0.0.1'
});

transmission.addUrl('my.torrent', {
    "download-dir" : "/home/torrents"
}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    var id = result.id;
    console.log('Just added a new torrent.');
    console.log('Torrent ID: ' + id);
    getTorrent(id);
});
```

Comment: hey ..when i am adding torrent file from module ,  "transmission-daemon" UI on port 9091 showing error "permission denied" during downloading and downloading stops immediately. I have tried your example in answer for transmission. Have you any idea regarding this...?

Comment: This is due to transmission's config, not to the given code. I've encontoured this issue many times. Try to change your folder's rights or owner. Otherwise, you may also change the user/group that transmission runs on.

Comment: hey ... thanks for your reply....it solved. Problem was that it's necessary to have +x permission on all parent folder, i.e /a/b/c/final then a,b and c should have +x permission. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not able to make it work(node-transmission) module. It shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0` evertime. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with video torrents, you may be interested in [Torrent Stream Server](https://github.com/KiraLT/torrent-stream-server). It a server that downloads and streams video at the same time, so you can watch the video without fully downloading it. It's based on [torrent-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/torrent-stream) library.

Another interesting project is [webtorrent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webtorrent). It's a nice torrent library that works in both: NodeJs & browser and has streaming support. From my experience, it doesn't have very good support in the browser, but should fully work in NodeJS.